# There's something undefined in my function

Tags: javascript

and I cannot spot it! The code above returns in console "undefinedipsum"

```
// At the end
// Call substring, passing "lorem ipsum dolor" to `input`, `6` to 
// `start`, and `10` to `end`.

var substring = function(input, start, end){
    var i;
    var subset;
    for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
        subset += input[i]
    }
    return subset;
}

console.log(substring("lorem ipsum dolor",6,10))
```

Comment: @ADC: No, it can be omitted (though I wouldn't recommend it)

Answer (score 4):

`subset` is undefined when the first concatenation is executed (and since you concatenate it with a string, `undefined` is converted to a string). Initialise `subset` with the empty string:

```
var substring = function(input, start, end){
    var i;
    var subset = "";
    for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
        subset += input[i];
    }
    return subset;
}
```

I think the real question though is why are you writing this yourself when there is a perfectly good [`String.prototype.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method already in existence?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Is there a reason you are writing your own `substring` function rather than using the built-in one?

Answer (score 2):

initialize the variable `subset`.

```
var subset ="";
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialise your variables.

```
var subset = '';
```

Otherwise you `+=` onto something that, to start with, is not a string.

i.e.

```
var x;
console.log(x+''); // "undefined"

x = x + 'a';
console.log(x);    // "undefineda"
```